# Labeling a map. Where is my syntax error in folium?

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to label a map in folium using geotadaframe from shp file but the error is the following:

```
AssertionError: Please pass a list or tuple to fields.
```

Here is the line in my code error:

```
folium.GeoJson(tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=MUNIC["Nome_Munic"], aliases=None, labels=True, localize=False, style=None, class_name='foliumtooltip', sticky=True)).add_to(mapa_A002)
```

Comment: That's not a syntax error. What is `MUNIC["Nome_Munic"]`? Apparently not a list or tuple.

Comment: On a line before i used that and worked but, used the field "geometry" and could stylize that, just to have an idea the worked last live is: folium.GeoJson(data=MUNIC["geometry"], style_function = lambda x: {"weight":4,"color":'#3579b1',"opacity":100,"fillColor": 'black', 'fillOpacity':0}).add_to(mapa_A002)